# Angular / Firestore - Set Reactive Form to pristine after saving document

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

My component has a form. My services handle the queries, saves and deletes. When a form is edited, the component has a save form function which calls the service to save the data. That works fine. However, upon saving I would like to mark the form as pristine. I don't believe my attempt is correct, as the `set` line in the service can be removed and the form will still be marked as pristine when saving.

**Component**

```
async saveForm(){
  await this.service.saveForm(form.value);
  this.form.markAsPristine();
}
```

**Service**

```
public async saveForm(value: Form) {
  this.afs.doc<Form>(`path`).set(formValue, {merge: true })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using promise chaining from your **service** and **component**

**service**:

```
  public async saveForm(Form) {
        this.afs.doc<any>(`path`).set(formValue, {merge: true }).then((result)=>{
          return result
    
        })
```

**component**:

```
this.yourservice.saveForm(form.value).then((result)=>{
      if(result){
        this.form.reset();
      }

    })
```

this is promise chaining -  after reviewing this with the questioner the answer changed to resetting the form.

Comment: Thanks @Chris - I receive the error on the component if statement: "An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness"

Comment: its doing what its supposed to do, try this.form?.markAsPristine() or
try this set the field name that you are trying to mark as pristine - not the entire form.

     this.form.get('YOURFIELDNAME')?.markAsPristine({onlySelf: true})




https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsPristine

Comment: Thanks Chris. Unfortunately didn't work. The error isn't on the pristine line, it's on the 'if(result){' - with 'result' being the error above. If that helps.

Comment: remove the if then and the result and just promise chain it 

this.yourservice.saveForm(form.value).then(()=>{
      
        this.form.markAsPristine();
 

    })

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've also tried that before my initial attempt. I can comment out the `this.afs` segment in the service so that it's an empty function, click save and the form will still return to being pristine, which leads me to believe that it's not correctly linked to the outcome of the database write.

Comment: after thinking about this further have you tried to just rest the form.  I am not sure why you would want to reset it to pristine, there may be some reason there.

form.resetForm();

Comment: Thanks Chris. At which point would you reset the form? Would you do it before performing 'patchValue' so that it's reset before the new values are added?

Comment: yes - you have to reset it in order, make sure you had a change detector ref as well.

import ChangeDetectorRef 
in your constructor private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef
at the end of your typescript for the service or oninit however you are invoking the form reset.

this.cdr.detectChanges()

Comment: Thanks Chris. Just performing a reset before patching seems to work fine. If you update your answer, I'll mark it as correct!